# Controlling async actions that might conflict in F#

Tags: concurrency, f#, async-await

I have many actions (`Async<T> list`) to perform in F#. I can execute *most* of these actions in parallel, but some might conflict due to file locks etc.

For each action, I can generate a "key" (`int`) that determines if the actions *might* conflict:

- If action `a` has key `i` and action `b` has key `j` and `i = j`, then `a` and `b` might conflict. They must be executed serially.
- If action `a` has key `i` and action `b` has key `j` and `i <> j`, then `a` and `b` will never conflict. They may be executed in parallel.

I would like to execute my actions `(int * Async<T>) list` in an efficient way and without conflicts.

I imagine that the process would be something like:

- Group all actions by key
- Chain each group serially into one `Async`
- Run each chain in parallel

How can I implement this in F#?

How are these problems usually handled?

---

My attempt at a fully sequential implementation:

```
let wrapTasks<'T> (tasks : (int * Async<'T>) list) : Async<'T list> = async {
  return
    tasks 
    |> Seq.map (fun (k, t) -> t |> Async.RunSynchronously)
    |> Seq.toList
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With a helper function taking a 'promise' for a value `x` and one for a set of values `acc`:

```
module Async =
    let sequence x acc = async {
        let! x = x
        let! y = acc
        return x :: y
    }
```

we can asynchronously group the `tasks` by their 'lock id', clean up the resulting list a bit and then `sequence` each group into a single `async` that 'contains' the list of the results of its group. This list is then processed in parallel. Once `ts : 'b list []` is available, we flatten it:

```
let wrapTasks tasks = async {
    let! ts =
        tasks
        |> List.groupBy fst
        |> List.map (snd >> List.map snd)
        |> List.map (fun asyncs -> List.foldBack Async.sequence asyncs (async { return [] }))
        |> Async.Parallel
    return ts |> List.ofArray |> List.collect id
}
```

This can be tested with e.g.

```
List.init 50 (fun i -> i % 5, async {
    let now = System.DateTime.UtcNow.Ticks
    do! Async.Sleep 10
    return i, now })
|> wrapTasks
|> Async.RunSynchronously
|> List.groupBy snd
|> List.map (fun (t, rs) -> t, rs |> List.map fst)
|> List.sort
```

By varying the divisor we can adjust the level of parallelism and convince ourselves that the function works as expected :-)

> ```
>   [(636766393199727614L, [0; 1; 2; 3; 4]);
>    (636766393199962986L, [5; 6; 7; 8; 9]);
>    (636766393200068008L, [10; 11; 12; 13; 14]);
>    (636766393200278385L, [15; 16; 17; 18; 19]);
>    (636766393200382690L, [20; 21; 22; 23; 24]);
>    (636766393200597692L, [25; 26; 27; 28; 29]);
>    (636766393200703235L, [30; 31; 32; 33; 34]);
>    (636766393200918241L, [35; 36; 37; 38; 39]);
>    (636766393201027938L, [40; 41; 42; 43; 44]);
>    (636766393201133307L, [45; 46; 47; 48; 49])]
> ```

<sub>Full disclosure: I had to execute the test a few times for getting this nice result. Usually numbers will be a bit off.</sub>

Answer (score 1):

This is a possible solution:

```
let wrapTasks (tasks : (int * Async<'T>) list) =
    tasks
    |> List.groupBy fst 
    |> Seq.map (fun (k, ts) -> async {
        for (i, t) in ts do
            let! r = t
            ()
    })
    |> Async.Parallel
    |> Async.RunSynchronously
```