# F# Async actions with conflicts / ordering / mutex

Tags: f#, async-await, mutex

F# makes it easy to define asynchronous computations using the `async` builder. You can write an entire program and then pass it to `Async.RunSynchronously`.

The problem I am having is that some `async` actions must not be run at the same time; they should be forced to wait for other `async` actions to complete. This is something like a mutex. However, I do not want to just chain them in serial because this would be inefficient.

**Concrete Example: Download Cache**

Suppose I want to fetch some remote files using a local file cache. In my application I call `fetchFile : Async<string>` in many places, but there is a risk that if I call `fetchFile` on the same URL at the same time, the cache will get corrupted by multiple writes. Instead, the `fetchFile` command should have behaviour like this:

- If there is no cache, download the file to the cache and then read the cache contents
- If the cache is currently being written to, wait for the write to finish and then read the contents
- If the cache is present and complete, just read the cache contents
- `fetchFile` on two different URLs should work in parallel

I am imagining some kind of stateful `DownloadManager` class to which requests can be sent and ordered internally.

How do F# programmers usually implement such logic with `async`?

---

Imaginary usage:

```
let dm = new DownloadManager()

let urls = [
  "https://www.google.com"; 
  "https://www.google.com"; 
  "https://www.wikipedia.org"; 
  "https://www.google.com"; 
  "https://www.bing.com"; 
]

let results = 
  urls
  |> Seq.map dm.Download
  |> Async.Parallel
  |> Async.RunSynchronously
```

---

Note: I previously asked [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53092395/controlling-async-actions-that-might-conflict-in-f) before about how to run `async` actions in a semi-parallel fashion, but now I have realized that this approach is hard to compose.

Note: I do not have to worry about multiple instances of the application running at once. In-memory locking is sufficient.

Answer (score 3):

**UPDATE**

Better than the lazy value is the `Async.StartChild` suggested by Petricek so I changed `lazyDownload` to `asyncDownload`

---

You could use a `MailboxProcessor` as a download manager that handles the cache. The MailboxProcessor is a structure in F# that processes a queue of messages ensuring no collisions.

First you need a processor capable of maintaining a state:

```
let stateFull hndl initState =
    MailboxProcessor.Start(fun inbox ->
        let rec loop state : Async<unit> = async {
            try         let! f        = inbox.Receive()
                        let! newState = f state
                        return! loop newState
            with e ->   return! loop (hndl e state)
        }
        loop initState
    )
```

The first parameter is a handler for errors, the second is the initial state, in this case a `Map<string, Async<string>>`. This is our `downloadManager`:

```
let downloadManager = 
    stateFull (fun e s -> printfn "%A" e ; s) (Map.empty : Map<string, _>)
```

To invoke the MailBox we need to use `PostAndReply`:

```
let applyReplyS f (agent: MailboxProcessor<'a->Async<'a>>) = 
    agent.PostAndReply(fun (reply:AsyncReplyChannel<'r>) -> 
        fun v -> async {
            let st, r = f v
            reply.Reply r
            return st 
        })
```

This function expects a folder function that checks the cache and adds an `Async<string>` if none is found and returns the updated cache.

First the `asyncDownload` function:

```
let asyncDownload url = 
    async { 
        let started = System.DateTime.UtcNow.Ticks
        do! Async.Sleep 30
        let finished = System.DateTime.UtcNow.Ticks
        let r = sprintf "Downloaded  %A it took: %dms %s" (started / 10000L) ((finished - started) / 10000L) url
        printfn "%s" r
        return r
    }
```

Just a dummy function that returns a string and timing information.

Now the folder function that checks the cache:

```
let folderCache url cache  =
    cache 
    |> Map.tryFind url
    |> Option.map(fun ld -> cache, ld)
    |> Option.defaultWith (fun () -> 
        let ld = asyncDownload url |> Async.StartChild |> Async.RunSynchronously
        cache |> Map.add url ld, ld
    )
```

finally our download function:

```
let downloadUrl url =
    downloadManager 
    |> applyReplyS (folderCache url)

// val downloadUrl: url: string -> Async<string>
```

**Testing**

```
let s = System.DateTime.UtcNow.Ticks
printfn "started %A" (s / 10000L)
let res = 
    List.init 50 (fun i -> i, downloadUrl (string <| i % 5) )
    |> List.groupBy (snd >> Async.RunSynchronously)
    |> List.map (fun (t, ts) -> sprintf "%s - %A" t (ts |> List.map fst ) )

let f = System.DateTime.UtcNow.Ticks
printfn "finish  %A" (f / 10000L)

printfn "elapsed %dms" ((f - s) / 10000L)

res |> printfn "Result: \n%A"
```

produces the following output:

```
started 63676683215256L
Downloaded  63676683215292L it took: 37ms "2"
Downloaded  63676683215292L it took: 36ms "3"
Downloaded  63676683215292L it took: 36ms "1"
Downloaded  63676683215291L it took: 38ms "0"
Downloaded  63676683215292L it took: 36ms "4"
finish  63676683215362L
elapsed 106ms
Result: 
["Downloaded  63676683215291L it took: 38ms "0" - [0; 5; 10; 15; 20; 25; 30; 35; 40; 45]";
 "Downloaded  63676683215292L it took: 36ms "1" - [1; 6; 11; 16; 21; 26; 31; 36; 41; 46]";
 "Downloaded  63676683215292L it took: 37ms "2" - [2; 7; 12; 17; 22; 27; 32; 37; 42; 47]";
 "Downloaded  63676683215292L it took: 36ms "3" - [3; 8; 13; 18; 23; 28; 33; 38; 43; 48]";
 "Downloaded  63676683215292L it took: 36ms "4" - [4; 9; 14; 19; 24; 29; 34; 39; 44; 49]"]
```

Comment: It will take me a while to digest this! Does this download different URLs in parallel? Only the same URLs should get queued up.

Comment: If you are in system where this cache might be accessed by multiple servers i.e. a number of scaled out webservers in a farm, I would suggest using Redlock.Net for a distributed lock, rather than a simple mailbox (https://github.com/samcook/RedLock.net)

Comment: I added some testing code and changed `Lazy` for `Async`. You can see how they all started at the same time and executed only once per Url.

Answer (score 3):

I agree with @AMieres that mailbox processor is a good way to do this. My version of the code is somewhat less general - it uses mailbox processor directly for this one purpose and so it might be a bit simpler.

Our mailbox processor has only one message - you ask it to download a URL and it gives you back an async workflow that you can wait for to get your result:

```
type DownloadMessage = 
  | Download of string * AsyncReplyChannel<Async<string>>
```

We need a helper function to asynchronously download a URL:

```
let asyncDownload url = async {
  let wc = new System.Net.WebClient()
  printfn "Downloading: %s" url
  return! wc.AsyncDownloadString(System.Uri(url)) }
```

In the mailbox processor, we keep a mutable `cache` (this is fine, because the mailbox processor processes messages synchronously). When we get a download request, we check if we already have download in the cache - if no, we start the download as a child `async` and add it to the cache - so the cache contains async workflows that represent results of a running download.

```
let downloadCache = MailboxProcessor.Start(fun inbox -> async {
  let cache = System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<_, _>()
  while true do
    let! (Download(url, repl)) = inbox.Receive()
    if not (cache.ContainsKey url) then 
      let! proc = asyncDownload url |> Async.StartChild
      cache.Add(url, proc)
    repl.Reply(cache.[url]) })
```

To actually download using cache, we just send a request to the mailbox processor and then wait for the result of the returned workflow (which may be shared by multiple requests).

```
let downloadUsingCache url = async {
  let! res = downloadCache.PostAndAsyncReply(fun ch -> Download(url, ch))
  return! res }
```

Comment: @AMieres Thanks for the correction. I'll delete my comment so that does not cause confusion.

Answer (score 2):

I am offering you a simplified version based on @Tomas Petricek answer.

---

Lets assume that we have our download function that given a url returns an `Async<string>`. This is a dummy version:

```
let asyncDownload url = 
    async { 
        let started = System.DateTime.UtcNow.Ticks
        do! Async.Sleep 30
        let finished = System.DateTime.UtcNow.Ticks
        let r = sprintf "Downloaded  %A it took: %dms %s" (started / 10000L) ((finished - started) / 10000L) url
        printfn "%s" r
        return r
    }
```

Here we have some simple generic `Mailbox` helper functions in their own module:

```
module Mailbox =
    let iterA hndl f =
        MailboxProcessor.Start(fun inbox ->
            async {
                while true do
                    try       let!   msg = inbox.Receive()
                              do!  f msg
                    with e -> hndl e
            }
        )
    let callA hndl f = iterA hndl (fun ((replyChannel: AsyncReplyChannel<_>), msg) -> async {
        let! r = f msg
        replyChannel.Reply r
    })
    let call hndl f = callA hndl (fun msg -> async { return f msg } )
```

The purpose of this 'library' is to simplify the more typical uses of the `MailboxProcessor`. While it looks complicated and hard to understand the important thing is what the functions do and how to use them.
In particular we are going to use `Mailbox.call` which returns a Mailbox agent capable of returning a value. It's signature is:

```
val call: 
   hndl: exn -> unit ->
   f   : 'a -> 'b    
      -> MailboxProcessor<AsyncReplyChannel<'b> * 'a>
```

The first parameter is an exception handler and the second a function that returns a value. Here is how we define our `downloadManager`:

```
let downloadManager = 
    let dict = new System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<string, _>()
    Mailbox.call (printfn "%A") (fun url ->         
        if dict.ContainsKey url then dict.[url] else
        let result = asyncDownload url |> Async.StartChild |> Async.RunSynchronously
        dict.Add(url, result)
        result
    )
```

Our cache is a `Dictionary`. If a url is not present we call `asyncDownload` and start it as a child process. By using `Async.StartChild` we do not have to wait until it finishes downloading, we just return an `async` that waits for it to finish.

To invoke the manager we use `downloadManager.PostAndReply`

```
let downloadUrl url = downloadManager.PostAndReply(fun reply -> reply, url)
```

And here is a test:

```
let s = System.DateTime.UtcNow.Ticks
printfn "started %A" (s / 10000L)
let res = 
    List.init 50 (fun i -> i, downloadUrl (string <| i % 5) )
    |> List.groupBy (snd >> Async.RunSynchronously)
    |> List.map (fun (t, ts) -> sprintf "%s - %A" t (ts |> List.map fst ) )

let f = System.DateTime.UtcNow.Ticks
printfn "finish  %A" (f / 10000L)

printfn "elapsed %dms" ((f - s) / 10000L)

res |> printfn "Result: \n%A"
```

That produces:

```
started 63676682503885L
Downloaded  63676682503911L it took: 34ms 1
Downloaded  63676682503912L it took: 33ms 2
Downloaded  63676682503911L it took: 37ms 0
Downloaded  63676682503912L it took: 33ms 3
Downloaded  63676682503912L it took: 33ms 4
finish  63676682503994L
elapsed 109ms
Result: 
["Downloaded  63676682503911L it took: 37ms 0 - [0; 5; 10; 15; 20; 25; 30; 35; 40; 45]";
 "Downloaded  63676682503911L it took: 34ms 1 - [1; 6; 11; 16; 21; 26; 31; 36; 41; 46]";
 "Downloaded  63676682503912L it took: 33ms 2 - [2; 7; 12; 17; 22; 27; 32; 37; 42; 47]";
 "Downloaded  63676682503912L it took: 33ms 3 - [3; 8; 13; 18; 23; 28; 33; 38; 43; 48]";
 "Downloaded  63676682503912L it took: 33ms 4 - [4; 9; 14; 19; 24; 29; 34; 39; 44; 49]"]
```